# Delete folder without certain content

Tags: windows-explorer, batch, file-management, user-folders

I would like to batch-delete all folders which don't contain a specific file.
It's about a working folder with hundreds of projects. I want to remove every folder that doesn't contain a "main.c". How can I do such thing? Is this possible in a batch file or should I use a special file explorer program?

Scenarios:
If there is `\proj1\main.c`, delete `\proj1`.
If there is no `\proj1\main.c`, but there is `\proj1\debug\main.c`, then aslo delete `\proj1`.

Comment: If there is `\foo\bar\main.c`, but there is no `\foo\main.c`, should `\foo` be deleted?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It looks like your title is wrong: it should be "Delete folder *with**out*** certain content".

Comment: Kamil yes, then \foo should be deleted

Comment: Do you need to recurse into subfolders, or just flat-check folders within a given folder? Assuming the toplevel folder's name is "Projects", there are two possible scenarios here: 1. Scan folders in "Projects". If a folder (for example "Projects\proj1") doesn't contain main.c directly, delete it.  2. Scan folders in "Projects" and all their subfolders. If a folder (or subfolder) doesn't contain main.c, delete it. (recursively). Please specify which scenario you require and update your question.

Comment: Your question is asking for two opposite things. Which one is correct? 1/ First you say "I want to remove every folder that doesn't contain a "main.c"." 2/ Then your scenario says "If there is \proj1\main.c, delete \proj1". If both of these statements are true then you are asking to delete both folders that contain the file and folders which do not contain the file. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that might work:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\parentdirectory\"
if exist "proj1\main.c" (rd /s"proj1")
if exist "proj1\debug\main.c" (rd /s "proj1")
cls
echo Done.
pause >nul
exit
```

It will tell you when it is done. Replace `parentdirectory` with the parent directory for `proj1`.

Comment: I disagree about this being a good question for Stack Overflow. Also, if it would have been, then people would have voted to move it there; no need to make people think they should post the same question again. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this answer will actually work. OP says "I would like to batch-delete all folders which **don't** contain a specific file.". Your answer **does the opposite**. In any case the whole question is unclear.

Comment: @DavidPostill Look at the last part of the question. I was right.

Comment: @CheezbergurKatt That's why I said his question is unclear. His scenarios don't agree with the text.